# How to Plumb Sink to Drain

Tags: plumbing

My vanity was roughed in with the waste outlet offset to where the sink ended up, as the vanity choice hadn't been made at the time.

As a result, I need to get the trap outlet over to the waste pipe.  I want to add a 45 to the waste outlet and then plumb the p trap into that.

Once the waste pipe is in the wall, it makes a 90 over to the waste/vent pipe. If I add a 45 under the sink, do I need a cleanout?

Also, any preference on the ABS trap vs pvc trap?
[[image: trap[1]]
[image: trap]

Answer (score 1):

1) You do not need to add a cleanout if you put a 45 elbow on your rough in. You probably want that 45 plus a short straight piece of ABS DWV to make it easy to adjust your P-trap.

2) Go with the PVC P-trap so you can easily adjust the location of your joints. You don't want to glue up the ABS and have to shift your tailpiece a fraction of an inch, or start at the tailpiece and have your trap glued to your drain pipe with just a tiny bit of engagement because your stub is a fraction of an inch too short.